# How to translate equal weight and sector weight?

Tags: translation

[RYE (Invesco S&P 500 Equal Weight Energy ETF)](https://www.etf.com/channels/equal-weighted-etfs) equally weighs each stock.

My attempt with Google Translate: RYE平均權衡每隻股票

SPY (SPDR S&P 500 ETF) sector weighs each stock.

My attempt: SPU按部門稱量每隻股票。

## Context

[Market Weight vs. Equal Weight S&P 500 ETFs](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/exchangetradedfunds/08/market-equal-weight.asp)

> Think of the S&P 500 like a pie chart: with a market weight ETF, the pie is broken up into slices based on market cap. With an [equal-weight](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/equalweight.asp) ETF, all the slices are the same size, regardless of the size of the company or sector.

Answer (score 1):

There is specific words used for financial terms in both English and Chinese.

equal weight: `等权(重)`

e.g.: 
equal weight index: `等权(重)指数`

equal weight ETF: `等权(重)交易所交易基金` or `等权(重)交易型开放式指数基金` or `等权(重)ETF` (ETF is very commonly known term in finance, so you can leave it as is)

weighted: `加权(重)`

e.g.: Price weighted index: `价格加权(重)指数`

SPDR S&P 500 generally known as `标普500`

sector is not `部门`. It is generally referring to `行业` in Finance